# Android Camera App - Have to Remount SD Card?

Tags: android, camera, sd-card

I am working on an app that uses the camera to take a picture and stores that picture on the SD Card. The problem is that after I take a save a picture, I have to unmount and remount the SD Card before I can see the picture in the Gallery app.

Should I unmount and remount the SD Card via my app, every time the user takes a picture? Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mount/unmount the SD card (external storage) from an app. You probably need to call media scanner to get your picture indexed. Look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) for pointers. There is also an sample app that comes with the SDK. BTW, what Android version are you testing on?

Comment: The phone is running Android v2.3.4

Comment: OK. On 2.x you should be able to see the actual file without scanning, but the gallery may not pick it up right away. Does calling the media scanner change anything?

Comment: I won't be able to look at this again until next week. I will report back then.

Comment: I followed the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250515/how-to-update-the-android-media-database

Comment: Yes, that's certainly works, but it will force a scan of the whole SD card/external storage directory. And since that's a system intent, it may or may not work in future versions.