# How to see the images saved in sd card android

Tags: android, image, android-sdcard

I have set of images downloaded from internet and saved those images in sd card.I wan to view the images.But it is not found in gallery.Where to view the images in sd card.

Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: In emulator or device ?

Comment: Also look at updating the Media database if your app is doing the  downloading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250515/how-to-update-the-android-media-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing in emulator then go to

**DDMS**->**file Explorer**->**mnt**->**Sdcard**

and if it is device then

**DCIM** or **Download** folder in sd Card...

See this screenshot

[image]

Comment: How to see the images stored in internal memory in device.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look for  `DCIM or Download` folder in sd Card