# On Android 11, after renaming media files on a removable micro-sd card, MediaStore can‘t be updated through the ContentResolver.update() method

Tags: android, mediastore, android-contentresolver

On Android 11 (API30) and above,  after renaming media files on a removable micro-sd card, MediaStore can‘t be updated through the ContentResolver.update() method. my targetSdkVison is 28.

I am not good at English, hope I can express myself clearly

this is my code:

```java
String oldPath = StorageKit.getSDcardPath()+"/Pictrues/20740534.jpg"; // oldPath:/storage/0COB-3B10/Pictrues/20740534.jpg;
String newPath = StorageKit.getSDcardPath()+"/Pictrues/travelPlan.jpg"; // newPath:/storage/0COB-3B10/Pictrues/travelPlan.jpg;

File img = new File(oldPath);
File file = new File(newPath);

boolean success = img.renameTo(file); // result is true

if (success) {
    Uri uri= MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    // result of "uri.toString()" is "content://media/external/images/media"
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
    // file.getAbsolutePath():/storage/0COB-3B10/Pictrues/travelPlan.jpg;
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/*");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, file.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, getForeString(file.getName(), '.'));
    contentResolver.update(uri, values, "_data=?", new String[]{oldPath});
}
```

Comment: Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(dbTable, values); Please tell value of uri.toString();

Comment: `this is my code:` That is not complete. You are not using the uri. Nor are you updating anything.

Comment: On Android 11 one does not use the .DATA column.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you. I have supplemented the problem description

Comment: @blackapps If the .DATA column is not used, an error will occur( `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Movement of content://media/external/images/media which isn't part of well-defined collection not allowed`)

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for your patient guidance. I have revised my problem description

Comment: `img.renameTo(file); // result is true` That is pretty amazing as since Android 4 KitKat removable micro-sd cards are read only (except for app specific files dir). So what did you do to make that possible?

Comment: It is unclear to me why you wanna update. Also i do not know what you wanna update.

Comment: Please post the relevant lines of the stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: If the only thing you want is updating the MediaStore to know the new file you could simply let it scan the file.

Comment: On Android 11+ one will not use the .DATA column but .RELATIVE_PATH and DISPLAY_NAME and use the contentUri() of the removable micro-sd card.

Comment: `// result of "uri.toString()" is "content://media/external/images/media"` But that is not the collection for a removable micro-sd card.

Comment: @blackapps `img.renameTo(file); // result is true` I don't know why, but it did succeed. both on AVD and my phone. I added 
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
to my androidManifest.xml

Comment: @blackapps I found someone who had the same experience，[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062168/media-scanner-for-secondary-storage-on-android-q?rq=2)

Comment: Ok. If the user agreed with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE then the micro-sd card becomes writable.

Comment: But please tell why you wanna update? I asked that before. Any reason not to tell?

Comment: @blackapps Update MediaStore records. If we don't do this, we won't be able to find it in the album after renaming the image file

Comment: Then let it scan. I said that before.

Comment: @blackapps `Then let it scan` Ok, but the records of the files before renaming will still be left in MediaStore. But there's no better way, thank you.

Comment: Yes there is a better way. Dont use File class to rename/move your file but let the MediaStore do it.

Comment: Or if you want to keep the File class to rename/move you after that query() the mediastore for the old file. If you get the uri for the file you use that uri to update().

Comment: @blackapps ok, I got it , thank you.